# Detect English verb tenses using NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am looking for a way given an English text count verb phrases in it in past, present and future tenses. For now I am using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org), do a POS (Part-Of-Speech) tagging, and then count say 'VBD' to get past tenses. This is not accurate enough though, so I guess I need to go further and use chunking, then analyze VP-chunks for specific tense patterns. Is there anything existing that does that? Any further reading that might be helpful? The [NLTK book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html) is focused mostly on NP-chunks, and I can find quite few info on VP-chunks.

Comment: There's a flaw in your logic. If a chunker can detect NP, then it must be able to detect VP.

Comment: Of course but I am mostly interested in further VP analysis - how to make a difference between different tenses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thee exact answer depends on which chunker you intend to use, but list comprehensions will take you a long way. This gets you the number of verb phrases using a non-existent chunker.

```
len([phrase for phrase in nltk.Chunker(sentence) if phrase[1] == 'VP'])
```

You can take a more fine-grained approach to detect numbers of tenses.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that's what I am gonna use - my next question is whether there is something existing to detect tense patterns. For each VP I'd like to know what tense is it in.

Comment: I actually managed to solve my problem with this approach, so tagging this as accepted answer. The following article is really helpful: http://streamhacker.com/2009/02/23/chunk-extraction-with-nltk/

Comment: Hi Michael, great to hear that things are working well for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with either the [Berkeley Parser](http://nlp.cs.berkeley.edu/Main.html) or [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).  But I don't know if there's a Python interface available for either.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this might be an option - however as I am heavily using NLTK already, it might be quite a lot of work to switch. Will look though.

Comment: There is an interface for the Stanford Parser in the NLTK. You can use it as follows: `tagger = nltk.tag.stanford.POSTagger('models/german-fast.tagger',
'stanford-postagger.jar')` You may have to encode the strings to UTF-8 first (at least for the German model).